# How can I remake this multiplication table with the lines

Tags: python

I need to remake a table with the following specifications:

> Create a multiplication table to match the one below.
> Use a nested loop to implement this. The outer loop runs through the rows, and the inner loop runs through the columns.
> Multiply the row and the column to get the product.
> There's a blank line (except for the | ) between rows.
> The top two lines can be printed out as constants, without using loops … but you may use loops if you want to.

[image: Screenshot of the specifications, and the table]

So far, I have gotten the numbers inside of the multiplication table down,

```
def Foo():
  print("    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12")
  print('=' * 66);
  
  for i in range(1, 13):
    for j in range(1, 13):
      print('{:>5}'.format(i * j),end='')
      if j == 12:
        print('\n')
  print()
Foo()
```

This is at least all the numbers and the top bar, I don't know how to make the left column and add the numbers and stuff.

P.S. I have no clue how this works: `print('{:>5}'.format(i * j),end='')`, I was told this is how to make it spaced out.

Comment: Your remark about not knowing what `print('{:>5}'.format(i * j),end='')` does is very unfortunate to hear. Now, I don't know if your professor did not explain the code, but it should be a prerequisite to at least *understand* the code before you attempt to refactor it... You cannot progress in your education without a solid foundation.

Comment: [Stack Overflow homework FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 2):

`print('{:>5}'.format(i * j),end='')` takes `i*j` and left pads it so the result is 5 characters long and `end=''` makes it so that a new line isn't added to the end of your print statement. This is convinient since other programming languages give you 2 print options `print` which is `print( ,end='')` in Python and `println` which is just `print` in Python.

```
print(f'    |{"".join([f"{i:>5}" for i in range(1,13)])}')
print('='*65)
for row in range(1,13):
    print(f'{row:>3} |', end='')
    for col in range(1,13):
        print(f'{row*col:>5}',end='')
    print('\n    |')
```

Edit: Here is the output:
[image]

Comment: @Codist that is an extremely fix, just change the `2` with `3` ... I'll update the code

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(1, 13):
    for j in range(1, 13):
        if j == 1:
            print(f" {i:2}|", end='')
        print('{:>5}'.format(i * j), end='')
        if j == 12:
            print(f'\n {"|":>3}')
print()
```

Comment: This does not produce the required output shown in the question

Answer (score -2):

Here's a different approach:

```
def row(m):
    return "".join(f"{i*m:>5}" for i in range(1, 13))

toprow = (p := "    |") + row(1)
print(toprow, "=" * len(toprow), sep="\n")
for i in range(1, 13):
    print(f"{i:>3} |{row(i)}\n{p}")
```